# Scatterplot to density heatmap in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, heatmap, scatter-plot

I have a scatterplot

[image]

But it's too dense. I Think I wold be great if this data was represented as a density heatmap as I can get in maps, like this:

[image]

Is there any way to achieve this? If it's not possible directly with PowerBI, I'll accept R or Python scripts objects for PowerBI

Answer (score 1):

You could use a matrix visual and put Age on one axis and Hour on the other, and then put the count (or whatever measure) on Values. On the matrix visual, turn off row and column subtotals. Then under Cell Elements, turn Background Color and Font Color ON, and you end up with a super simple heatmap. You can modify the colors to your liking by adjusting the Minimum, Maximum and middle colors.

Comment: A great option! The result is too big (as it shows the total as a number for each cell), but it's another approach to show my data. Thanks!